# pop up authentication pressing cancel on c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Hi everyone I'm trying to press the cancel button on the following picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEl26.png)

Note the following:
Im not really a coder and I am very new to selenium.
There is no web element to select so Im trying to select the cancel button
using the image based way, see below:

```
public void testlogin()
    {
        APILauncher launch = new APILauncher(true);
        launch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(8000);
        Screen scr = new Screen();
        Pattern Image1 = new Pattern("C:\\Selenium\\Cancel-button");
        scr.Click(Image1); 
    }
```

I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMiwT.png)

```
Result StackTrace:  
Result Message: 
Sikuli4Net.sikuli_UTIL.SikuliActionException : Result: FAILorg.sikuli.script.Pattern cannot be cast to java.lang.String
TearDown : System.InvalidOperationException : chrome not reachable
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.91)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (100)
```

Comment: Please provide **error messages as text**. There is no need to use that much network traffic and storge space just for an image of a message. It also requires more time from each reader to go and visit the external site.

Comment: I have added the error in text

Comment: soo.. why does the error say it can't be cast to `java.lang.String`? I thought this is a c# error? I am confused

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Sikuli so I can't help a lot, but I see where the error is.

This error says that you can't post string to `Pattern`:

This is where you made your error:

```
Pattern Image1 = new Pattern("C:\\Selenium\\Cancel-button");
```